# What does "capacity" mean in this question?

Tags: vocabulary

> How long have you known this referee and in what capacity

I'm filling my university application I met this question which befuddled me.

Does it mean "are you familiar with the referee"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. This is the [fourth definition for "capacity" in the Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capacity?show=0&t=1287431603):

> duty, position, role

So, possible answers to "in what capacity" here would be, for example:

- I worked with the referee at company XYZ, where we were both software developers.
- The referee was my Maths teacher at school.

And an answer to the full question "How long have you known this referee and in what capacity" would be, for example:

- I worked with [name] from January 2007 to March 2009 at company XYZ, where we were both software developers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. According to my Google result, my people give the wrong answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno probably has the correct answer, but in this case I read "in what capacity?" as "in what way and to what extent?"

Comment: Fortunately, those are basically the same answers.  "In what way" and "in what role" are close enough.